# How to add shading through all subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a question about add shading in my figure. I need to shading all subplot like the picture below, how to do it in Python?
[image]

Comment: Please provide a minimal working code snippet describing your problem and your efforts to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `clip_on=False` in a `Rectangle patch` so that it can extend beyond the axis boundaries.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import numpy as np

fig,ax=plt.subplots(2,1)

x=np.linspace(0,np.pi*2,50)

ax[0].plot(x,np.sin(x),'b-')
ax[1].plot(x,np.sin(x),'b-')

rect=mpatches.Rectangle([0.35,0.1], 0.1, 0.8, 
         ec='k', fc='g', alpha=0.5, clip_on=False, transform=fig.transFigure)
ax[1].add_patch(rect)

fig.savefig('figure.png')
```

[image]

Note: setting the rectangle on the first axis would have made it go behind the second axis, unless you want to manually change the zorder of the two axes.